# Best way to convert ostream to std::vector<uint8_t>

Tags: c++

I am trying to find the most efficient way of converting an `std::ostream` to a `std::vector<uint8_t>`. I could obviously convert to string first but I am trying to avoid extra data copies. Is there a nice way to do this? I have been looking at the rdbuf of ostream and think that it might be doable using that. Not sure how to proceed though. Any advice?

Comment: Looks like that's not doable. All needed methods are protected by their respective classes. You can't access the put area of `basic_streambuf`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mistake ostream with istream (because you're reading input into the vector) you're probaply looking for [istream_iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator). You can pass them to the constructor of vector:

```
std::istringstream str("5 16 32 8");
std::vector<uint8_t> numbers{ std::istream_iterator<int>(str), std::istream_iterator<int>() };
```

Note that you have to pass int as argument to the iterator, because operator<< is not defined for uint8_t.

Comment: You are wrong saying *operator<< is not defined for uint8_t.* The operator `>>` is indeed defined (see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt2) for `uint8_t`, it just treats the input as characters (as opposed to numbers)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean `istream` (input) and not `ostream` (output), then `istream` has a [`read()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read) method for reading input into a user-provided buffer.  So, simply pre-allocate your `vector` to the desired size and then `read()` directly into its data buffer, eg:

```
std::vector<uint8_t> buffer(size);
stream.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(buffer.data()), size);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to read file contents without parsing:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iterator>

std::vector<uint8_t> read_data(std::istream& s) {
    return std::vector<uint8_t>(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>{s},
                                std::istreambuf_iterator<char>{});
}

int main() {
    auto v = read_data(std::cin);
}
```

The drawback is that you cannot specify the maximum size to read. If that is a requirement (a public API that you want to protect from unfriendly clients), use `istream::read` with a fixed size, as Remy Lebeau advises.

If the file is large (e.g. megabytes or more), you may like to map directly into memory to avoid large data copies and memory reallocations.